# Laravel 5.6 upload image

Tags: php, laravel, image, laravel-5.6

I want to upload images with laravel:I created the field in mysql:

```
imagepath varchar 250
```

Created the form:

```
<form  method="post" id="formId" action="/ticket" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group ">...other fields
       <div class="form-group">
           <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="imageFile" id="imageFile" aria-describedby="fileHelp">
       </div>
```

In my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $fileName = request()->imageFile->getClientOriginalExtension();
    dd($fileName);//echos ".jpg"
    $tickes = Users::create(['imagePath' => $fileName]);
}
```

However my db is always null!I want to store it in my public/storage folder in Laravel.
Please help!

Comment: append `imagePath` to `$fillable`  in  `User` model

Comment: @Alihosseinshahabi omg I totally forgot to update my model,but I still dont think it it right?now it saves it my db but its like this 1528305497.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this code for upload image to `public/storage/ directory :

```
if ($request->hasFile('input_img')) {
    if($request->file('input_img')->isValid()) {
        try {
            $file = $request->file('input_img');
            $name = rand(11111, 99999) . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

            # save to DB
            $tickes = Users::create(['imagePath' => 'storage/'.$name]);

            $request->file('input_img')->move("storage", $name);
        } catch (Illuminate\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException $e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the route is public/storage

Comment: and if could aslo show me how to display a link that open this image would be wonderful

Comment: ok, I change location.please test again. this code save image in `public/storage` directory

Comment: `->move("img", $name);` doesnt it move to the img folder couse I only want it to the storage folder

Comment: do I need to the last part?it looks like it moves the img to a sub folder can you please update your question

Comment: please add also how do I retrieve this?

Comment: for example  you can retrieve by : `{{asset($user->imagePath)}}` in your `view`

Answer (score 0):

1. This code is only saving the file extension, not the image path.
2. You need to save the file to storage before your database can get a path to it.
   Laravel has really good documentation and this link will help you figure this out. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem